# CASTING a number in a TEXT datatype to DOUBLE returns 0 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a coulmn of number which is saved in TEXT datatype.
When i want to CAST it to DOUBLE datatype it returns 0.
Here is my data

| product_price |
| --- |
| $9.99 |
| $89.85 |
| $89.85 |
| $89.85 |
| $89.85 |
| $799.99 |
| $58.89 |
| $45.99 |
| $399.95 |
| $299.99 |
| $234.50 |
| $199.95 |
| $169.95 |
| $169.95 |
| $169.95 |
| $13.99 |
| $13.99 |
| $13.99 |
| $13.99 |
| $13.99 |
| $1,000.00 |
| $1,000.00 |
| $1,000.00 |
| $1,000.00 |
| $1,000.00 |
| $1,000.00 |
| $1,000.00 |
| $1,000.00 |
| $1,000.00 |

my code is here:

```
SELECT CAST(product_price AS DOUBLE)
FROM test_db.transactions
ORDER BY product_price DESC;
```

and the return vales are as follows:

| CAST(product_price AS DOUBLE) |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |

I will be grateful if someone can help me handle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `$` sign can't be converted to double. First, you have to remove the `$` sign then double the value

```
SELECT replace(product_price, '$', '') + 0.0 as product_price FROM products order by product_price desc;
```

Comment: thanks alot that works for all data expect for 1,000.00

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports casting into `DECIMAL`.
You can see more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp)
But the problem you have is mentioned in the above answers,
half the solution can be taken from there:

You can use the following:

```
SELECT 
CAST(REPLACE(c.`product_price`,'$','') AS DECIMAL) as product_price 
FROM products c;
```

Here is a link to [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bcd540/1)

Answer (score 0):

Both `$` and `,` signs need to be removed from the value before casting, so that `$1,000.00` becomes `1000.00` first:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
  REPLACE(REPLACE(product_price, ",", ""), "$", "")
  AS DOUBLE
)
FROM test_db.transactions
ORDER BY product_price DESC;
```

Side note:

As [mentioned above by @ergest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76826910/22236254), better use `DECIMAL(20,4)` type for amounts, together with additional `currency CHAR(3)` field specifying, well, currency of the amount. Or, if prices in this table are by design in USD (even if sold on other markets), then the field should be `product_price_usd`. The world is big, don't limit yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Strings that start with a non-numeric character are treated as `0` when type conversion is attempted.

> The following examples illustrate conversion of strings to numbers for comparison operations:
>
> mysql> SELECT 1 > '6x';
> -> 0
> mysql> SELECT 7 > '6x';
> -> 1
> mysql> SELECT 0 > 'x6';
> -> 0
> mysql> SELECT 0 = 'x6';
> -> 1

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)